# angular CLI application in node server does not build on file change

Tags: angularjs, node.js, angular-cli

I have an angular CLI application on node server. how can auto build this when ever a file changes in the angular CLI app. i was using lite server before and currently i converted it to node server for writing a JSON file. can anyone guide me

Comment: your question is unclear. angular-cli's `ng serve` will run the app in a node server, listen for file changes and update OOTB.

Comment: @AhmedMusallam hello thank you for the reply. i was not using the default server because i want to process a post request so used different node server. I have to use ng build and node server.js to run the application. is there any alternative to get notified all the changes in the angular client.

Comment: 'ng serve' will run a webpack-dev-server, which is a node server. You can probably use that as your node server. Not sure exactly how you are using your current node server. Alternatively, you can lookup "watch directory and exec" and you'll find many tutorials on how to watch a directory, then build and deploy. Note this will be. Very very slow.